# Validating a string with exceptions

Tags: java, arrays, string, validation, exception

I'm writing a program that suppose to read in a string from the user and validate the string and the operands. The only two acceptable operands are "+" and "-". The string cannot contain any characters other than numbers if it does, it should say "Bad input" but keep prompting the user. I have pasted my code below and we are suppose to use exceptions for this program. My code is not working and it crashes and those numbers need to be summed up and printed out but I'm having trouble doing that with  the operands that are in the string

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String term;

    do {
        String str = input.nextLine();
        term = str.trim();

        try {
            System.out.println(validInput(str));
            System.out.println(sumNums(str));
        } catch (IllegalOperandException e) {
            System.out.println("Bad Input");
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Bad Input");
        }

    } while (term.length() > 0);

}

public static String validInput(String string) throws IllegalOperandException {
    String output = "";
    String[] stringArray = string.split("\\s+");
    for (String s : stringArray) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if (!(Character.isDigit(c) || c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '.' )) {
                throw new IllegalOperandException(String.valueOf(c));
            }
            else if(Character.isDigit(c)){
                Double.parseDouble(Character.toString(c));
            }
        }
        output = output + s + " ";
    }
    return output;


}

public static double sumNums (String nums) throws NumberFormatException, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException { 
    String[] stringArray2 = nums.split("\\s+"); 
    int i = 0;
    int sum; 

    if (stringArray2[i].equals("-")) { 
        i++;
        sum = Integer.parseInt(stringArray2[i]);    
    } else
        sum = Integer.parseInt(stringArray2[i]); 

    for(int j = 0; j < stringArray2.length; j++) {      

        if (stringArray2[i].equals("+"))    
            sum+=Integer.parseInt(stringArray2[i-1]);
        if (stringArray2[i].equals("-"))
            sum-=Integer.parseInt(stringArray2[i+1]);
    } 
    return sum; 


} 


}
```

Comment: What concrete error do you get?

Comment: when I input a string of characters, it suppose to say "Bad input" and it makes the user prompt again but it is giving me this "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method IllegalOperandException(char) is undefined for the type TEST

 at TEST.validInput(TEST.java:44)
 at TEST.main(TEST.java:21)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to throw an exception you have to create new object. So, correct way to do so will be

```
throw new IllegalOperandException(c);
```

Second, you pass a character to a constructor, but constructor can accept only `String`. You can create second constructor in your `IllegalOperandException` class

```
public IllegalOperandException(char c){
    this(String.valueOf(c)); //this will call IllegalOperandException(String) constructor
}
```

or you can change line where you throw an exception to this

```
throw new IllegalOperandException(String.valueOf(c));
```

Third, `return false` is unreachable. If you throw an exception, code execution jumps directly to `catch` statement and your `validInput(String)` can't return anything (it has nowhere to return value). So, you don't need it

Comment: omg it works now but now when i try this test case like this " 3231 + sdsa" it suppose to only say "Bad Input" but the output is "3231 + Bad Input" and where do I add the while loop so after the user gets the "Bad Input" message the user can input different values, The program is suppose to terminate when the user enters an empty string

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/6de47c5d4929d2efce14) is slightly modified version. Although I would use just regular expressions, then all the checks could be shrinked down to 3-4 lines

Comment: How would you sum up the integers like 232 + 10 it would be 242 and it would keep prompting the user to do more problems just like that till the user enters whitespaces

Comment: [Here's](https://gist.github.com/Meegooo/3f30cc21a46200656da7) slightly better version

Comment: I need to sum up the numbers that are inputted by the user, how do I do that? for example a test case would be like this "4343.5 + 10 - 15" which would output "4348.5"

Comment: In a nutshell, you can split on spaces, iterate through each member of the array and look for `+` and `-` signs. When you get one, you look at previous (`i-1`) member and next (`i+1`) member, parse them to `Integer` using `Integer.parseInt()` and sum/subtract them. Then you can replace next (`i+1`) element with your new sum/subtraction and continue the loop. Of course then stupid user could write something like "123 456 + + 123" which would pass the validation but won't work as expected (it would throw `NumberFormatException` because `+`  can't be parsed into `Integer`).

Comment: Also, your paser would fail when it meets dot. I suggest you use regular expressions for validation purposes. But I can't help you with those.

Comment: Whelp, you can't split on spaces if input would be something like "123+123". So, you can do that `String fixedString = string.replace("+", " + ").replace("-", " - ").replaceAll(" +", " ")`. That will convert strings like "123+123    -    123" to "123 + 123 - 123" which you can parse using the way above

Comment: I wrote the method of summing them up but it crashs and doesn't work

Comment: public static double sumNums (String nums) throws NumberFormatException {
 double sum;
 String[] stringArray2 = nums.split("\\s+");
  for(String s : stringArray2) {
   for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    if(c == '+')
     sum += Integer.parseInt(stringArray[i-1]);
  else if(c == '-')
     sum -= Integer.parseInt(stringArray[i+1]);
    
   }
   return sum;
  }
return sum;
}
}

Comment: Something like that i think https://gist.github.com/Meegooo/5c913f1b0925268eac7d

Comment: I used that code you provided with some edits but it still doesn't sum up and I get the wrong output

Comment: I edited the main question and put my recent code up there